# Student Management

Tags: c++, beginner

> You are a computer science professor at South Harmon Institute of
> Technology, and are in dire need of automatic grading! The good news
> is you have all of your student's assignments in an easy-to-read
> format, making automation easy!
>
> You will be given a list of unique student names, and then a list of
> their assignment grades. All assignments are based on 20 points and
> are scored in whole-numbers (integers). All students have received the
> same number of assignments, so you don't have to worry about managing
> jagged arrays.

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class grades {
public:
    friend std::ostream &output(std::ostream &os, grades&);
        friend bool inputGrades(grades &test, const std::vector<std::string> &students, const std::vector<double> &tests);

    bool setAmmount(unsigned, unsigned);
    void genGrades();
    void clear() {numStudents = 0; numTests = 0;}    
private:

    std::vector<double> getGrades() const {return Grades;} 
    std::vector<std::string> getStudents() const {return Names;}

    unsigned numStudents;
    double numTests;
    double totalNumTests;
    std::vector<double> Grades;
    std::vector<std::string> Names;
};

    bool grades::setAmmount(unsigned nStud, unsigned nTest) {
    if(nStud >= 1 && nStud <= 60 && nTest >= 4 && nTest <= 100) {
        numStudents = nStud;
        numTests = nTest;
        totalNumTests = nStud * nTest;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool inputGrades(grades &test, const std::vector<std::string> &students, const std::vector<double> &tests) {
    if(test.totalNumTests != tests.size() || test.numStudents != students.size())
        return false;
    test.Grades = tests;
    test.Names = students;
    return true;
}

void grades::genGrades() {
    unsigned tempNum = 0; double TempGrade = 0; std::vector<double> newGrades;
    if(Grades.size() != totalNumTests || Names.size() != numStudents) { 
        return;
    }
    for(auto c = Grades.begin(); c != Grades.end(); ++c) {
    ++tempNum;
    TempGrade += *c;
        if (tempNum == numTests) {
            TempGrade /= tempNum;
            newGrades.push_back(TempGrade);
            TempGrade = 0; tempNum = 0;
        }
    }
    Grades = newGrades;
    return;
}

std::ostream &output(std::ostream &os, grades &test) {
    auto grades = test.getGrades(); auto students = test.getStudents();
    auto size = students.size();
    for(unsigned cnt = 0; cnt != size; ++cnt) {
        os << students[cnt] << " " << grades[cnt] << std::endl;
    }
    return os;
}
```

Expected input/output:

#### Input:

> 3 5
>
> JON 19 14 15 15 16
>
> JEREMY 15 11 10 15 16
>
> JESSE 19 17 20 19 18

#### Output:

> 15.93
>
> JON 15.80
>
> JEREMY 13.40
>
> JESSE 18.60

Comment: I notice that you changed the code in the question 2 minutes before the first answer. I doubt the answering person reviewed that revision. In general, avoid changing code after you've posted a question.

Comment: I noticed just noone answered yet so I changed it up but the changes I made didnt change the answer that much

Answer (score 4):

#### What is `grades` actually?

What is this class supposed to represent? It has a `vector<int>` for the individual test grades, which leads me to believe that based on your example, we might have one `grades` for `JON` containing `{19, 14, 15, 15, 16}` and another for `JEREMY`, etc. But then you also have a `vector<string>` for the students. So it's unclear what the usage of this class is. It's trying to do too many things - that's bad design.

This is made all the more confusing by `genGrades()` which alters the contents of `Grades` to be something else entirely. You also have issues with integer division - you have no way of being able to print `15.80` since nothing is ever a `double` or `float`.

A better design would be to **separate your concerns**. Have a class that is an individual student. A student has a `name` and some `scores` (don't keep reusing the word "grades" to mean different things):

```
struct Student {
    std::string name;
    std::vector<int> scores;
};
```

A student might also know how to compute their own average:

```
struct Student {
    std::string name;
    std::vector<int> scores;

    double average() const;
};
```

And then all you need is a container of them:

```
std::vector<Student> students;
```

This makes it clear what's going on. The `average()` member function will give you the average score, **without** any modification. That will make it easy to reason about and have the code much clearer. For instance, most of the output is just:

```
for (const Student& student : students) {
    std::cout << student.name << " " << student.average() << '\n';
}
```

#### Class I/O in C++

The way you make classes streamable in C++ is with `operator<<`, not a function named `output()`. The reason for this is so you can write:

```
grades g(...);
std::cout << "Grades are: " << g;
```

Similarly, input should be spelled `operator>>` so that you could write:

```
grades g;
std::cin >> g;
```

It makes the interaction the same with your class as it is with any other class.

That said, your `inputGrades()` doesn't actually input anything. It seems more like a constructor:

```
grades(const std::vector<int>&, const std::vector<std::string>& );
```

#### One line per line

One of the things that makes it very hard to read your code is you do things like:

```
auto grades = test.getGrades(); auto students = test.getStudents();
```

There is no reason for that! Vertical space isn't at a premium, and it is MUCH easier to read this:

```
auto grades = test.getGrades();
auto students = test.getStudents();
```

(Although since both of those functions return by-value, you're making unnecessary copies here as well. Prefer to return by reference to const, and then don't alias them. )